# Have strings; do not know how to run on MS Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line

This is as basic as it comes I am sure. I need to convert binary files on my laptop (MS Windows 10) to ASCII. I have downloaded strings from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

I have unzipped it.

1. Where should I have the strings.exe, strings64.exe files stored?
2. How do I run the `strings` command? I'm assuming from "run"?

Comment: Somewhere setting the PATH environment variable or else just copy to `C:\Windows\System32` right there... then it should run from CMD regardless.... Path or `~\system32`....

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 32-bit system, copy strings.exe to `C:\Windows\System32\`.

If you have a 64-bit system, rename strings64.exe to strings.exe and then copy it to `C:\Windows\System32\`.

From the sysinternals website :
usage: **strings [-a] [-f offset] [-b bytes] [-n length] [-o] [-q] [-s] [-u]**

You can run strings in the command prompt :

> C:\WINDOWS\system32> **strings * | findstr /i Example**

or from the Run window...

> **strings.exe * | findstr /i Example**

<sub>*The code given is only an example. You can insert your own code.*</sub>